# Div's changing position with window resize

Tags: css

I have a problem that I've literally been struggling with the whole day. 
I have two divs aligned next to each other. The problem is when I resize the browser window(smaller), the right div jumps below the left div. I specified a fixed width for the containing parent and I made sure that the two inside divs widths do not exceed the parent div's width. My markup:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">contents</div>
  <div class="right">contents</div>
</div>

<style>
 .parent
 {
   width: 800px;
 }

 .left
 {
   float: left;
   width: 305px;
 }

 .right
 {
   display: inline-block; (also tried float: left)
   width: 480px;
 }
</style>
```

I really need help on this, I'm going crazy.
Thank You

Comment: why not try float:right for .right?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that in Firefox 12, see http://jsfiddle.net/jeroen/3RNKx/ Do you have a valid doctype?

Comment: If you're serious about finding out what's wrong with your project, then you'll need to provide a link to it. It's apparent that this layout is being interfered with by some other code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code plugged into jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FHqtK/

There must be some other styles interfering because it behaves just fine here with `float: left`.

Comment: Chrome's inspect element shows that my containing div has another width than I specified. i literally took out code by code but nothing solves it. I just cannot find what is causing it

Comment: @DextrousDave You're better off providing a link to your project then, because what you've supplied has no theoretical issues.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your divs are the width that you specified? They might have margin or padding. Also, I hope the code you posted isn't exactly the same as the code you're working with. A style tag should be inside head tags.

Your structure should look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XEamY/

Comment: Thanks. No the styles are in a stylesheet. I literally took everything out of the right div, and with those widths specified, I still have that resize problem. There is no way that my widths are wrong

Comment: I can't see that you've specified margin or width anywhere. The box model is a little strange in that the actual width is calculated as width + border + padding. Try specifying `margin:0;padding:0`.

Comment: Also, if you're floating the divs, they should not be inline-block.

Comment: I'm only floating the left div. Should I make it inline-block as well?

Comment: No, both divs should be block elements, and they should both be floating left. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JezenThomas I think we can both agree that it's clear there's nothing wrong with the code that DextrousDave has offered us.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  .right {
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: normal;
        width: 480px;
    }
```

Comment: How about setting up white-space property of parent div to nowrap?